# call MFC DLL with MinGw

Tags: c++, gcc, dll, mfc

I have a Problem with DLL's.

now in my dll I have this class, compiled with MVSC12:

```
#ifdef DLL_EXPORTS
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class  DLL_API ExpClass
{
public:
   ExpClass()
   {

   }

   ~ExpClass()
   {

   }

   const char* getHelloWorld()
   {
      return "Hello World";
   }

   void initMainInstance();
};
```

I call is compiled with MinGW or with MVSC12.

```
ExpClass* tempExportClass = new ExpClass();

qDebug() << "Pointer to Export Class: " << tempExportClass;
qDebug() << tempExportClass->getHelloWorld();

tempExportClass->initMainInstance();
```

The call to the Constructor and to getHelloWorld its working fine
But by the call from "initMainInstance" is not work

the compiler bring this error message:
main.cpp:18: Fehler: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8ExpClass16initMainInstanceEv'

Comment: This looks like you got lucky with the compiler. Since it can see the entire implementation in the header file, it simply optimized the calls into the DLL away. This is not true for the `initMainInstace()` member, though, which does generate a call. For this to work, you need to provide the DLL's import library. As an aside, mixing compilers across an ABI is not a good idea.

Comment: You can't share C++ classes unless both *.dll and *.exe are made with the same version of Visual Studio. You can still use C function calls to link *.exe and *.dll between gcc and Visual Studio. Use `extern "C"` to resolve name mangling.